# Passing List<KeyValuePair<short, long>> to Android(java) from C#

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I;m using Unity v5.2.6.f1.

I need to pass `List<KeyValuePair<short, long>>` parameter to android(java) from C#

I tried to call Java method below way in C#

```
public static void test(List<KeyValuePair<short, long>> param) {
    AdnroidJavaClass.CallStatic("method", param);
}
```

and I got exception message

> Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int16,System.Int64]]' (obj = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int16,System.Int64]])

so I changed list to array and tried again.

```
public static void test(List<KeyValuePair<short, long>> param) {
    AdnroidJavaClass.CallStatic("method", param.ToArray());
}
```

and I got exception message again.

> Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int16,System.Int64]' (obj = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int16,System.Int64])

Comment: try other data structures like Dictionary or Hashtable

Comment: @UmairM Dictionary or Hashtable can be passed to java?? 
i used Dictionary, and i got exception message, too.
Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int16,System.String]' (obj = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int16,System.String])

Comment: what is your android side code?

Comment: @UmairM for example public static void test(Map<int, int> arg1) {}

Comment: I am facing the same issue.